# How to check with is_page if 404.php is loaded?

Tags: conditional-tags

I want to check if current page match at least one of two conditions. I don't want to show js code into about page and into 404 page. For the rest of my pages i show the js code. So, I use `((!is_page(element1) AND  !is_page(element2))` then show the js code. Element1 is a slug of one specific page and element2 is 404.php page. I don't know the slug or name of 404 page to indicate in if statement.

Comment: I don't get how a page could be a template `element1.php` and a `404` page in the same time ? It's one or the other - 404 is by definition a 'ressource not found' so it does not use any template but the 404.php template.

Comment: I need a trigger that works if _any_ of two conditions match. I display a search form for each page only if it is not a main page or if it is not a 404 page where other search form is included in body. my new code works well for my blog

Comment: "if any of two conditions match" = `OR`statement.

Comment: Your description is inconsistent with the accepted answer, which has been edited (by you, @Yurij73) since @Simon published it. You say you want "at least one of two conditions" to match, but the answer requires both conditions to match. That is an `||`, as @Simon originally had it, not an `&&`. This is going to lead to a lot of confusion. Please clean up the question.

Comment: Exactly as @Simon say 0 for any of two condition. That was a cible. I'm correcting my question now to expose question in a right way.

Comment: @Yurij73 In future, please post any feedback as a comment on the question/answer, instead of directly editing the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do :

```
if ( is_page( 'element1.php' ) || is_404() ) {
// do that  if page is using template page element1.php or is 404
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A 404 page probably doesn't have a `slug`. It is created automagically like the tag and category pages archive pages

Now, [`is_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) doesn't tell you anything about the template being used, which you seem to be thinking about checking for when you say and "and element2 is 404.php page". [`is_page_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) will. So...

```
if (is_page('element1') || is_page_template('404.php')) {
  // stuff
}
```

Will trigger if page-slug == element1 is loaded or if a page is loading that uses `404.php`. But `404.php` is not a necessary theme file so looking for the template may not be what you want. You probably want to use `is_404` as in Simon's answer (which you should "accept" if you go with `is_404`).